# Why does this piece of VBA code ask for the VBA-project password?

Tags: vba

This strange thing happens on my collegues desktop computer:

We share the same *.docm files with inside each file a password protected VBA-project. If I open the document, all is fine it opens and nothing is prompted. But if he opens he gets prompted for the VBA-project password.

If we enter the password then an error is higlighted. But that piece of code is in many documents and it has never ever caused any problems before. Also I do not understand what the error should be.

This is the code used:

```
For Each aWindow In Windows
aWindow.View.ShowBookmarks = True
Next aWindow
```

This is the source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.view.showbookmarks

The highlighted part / error would be aWindow after For Each.

Thanks for any help.

I tried to figure out the problem but the aWindow is just an item in a collection...

Comment: Please, tell us **exactly how "he gets prompted for the VBA-project password"**. Are you sure that isn't it about an error being raised and it cannot show the problematic code line because of the VBProject protection?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for taking time.

As I read my question and next your answer then a part of the solution gets clear. Yes you are right, if the VBA-project had not been password protected then the VBA-editor would just pop up and mark the word/item 'aWindow' in a yellow color.

My question therefore is not formulated correctly, I apologize.

The question I should have put out is this: why would this piece of code return an error in just one document and not in many other (which contain the exact same VBA-code)?

```
For Each aWindow In Windows
aWindow.View.ShowBookmarks = True
Next aWindow
```

Comment: I just found out that the Word documents do differ at one point: 1 is connected to an Excel data sheet and the other Word document isn't. It seems the Excel file is stuck on the server. I mean: it is in use by someone but it is not...  will seek a solution on the server and try to 'free Excel'.